# Why cant I use the $SVN_EDITOR environment variable in cygwin?

Tags: svn, cygwin

I must be missing something stupid! It works fine when I use the -m option.

```
$ echo $SVN_EDITOR
emacs

$ svn commit test.py
svn: Commit failed (details to follow):
svn: Could not use external editor to fetch log message; consider setting the $SVN_EDITOR envirionment variable or using the --message (-m) or --file (-F) options 
svn: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no 'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have never seen a platform where SVN_EDITOR actually works -- it doesn't work on Mac OS X either. Use EDITOR, it should work fine.

Comment: Have you exported the variable? You must use `export EDITOR`.

Comment: Silly me. I was exporting SVN_EDITOR, but I didn't realize I had to export even when assigning the $EDITOR variable in the shell. Thanks so much.

Comment: SVN_EDITOR works fine on debian based platforms, I think it fallsback to EDITOR if not set.

Comment: stackoverflow Q: “how do I do **x**?” A: “you can’t do **x**, you must do **y**”

Answer (score 11):

Though this is a cygwin question, I would like to state that on windows command line when using svn command line (collabnet), you could use the following

```
set SVN_EDITOR=notepad.exe
```

I am stating this hear since it might help windows users and did not find anything else related to this on other SO questions.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you can try adding this line to your ~/.bashrc file:

export SVN_EDITOR=emacs

Comment: This works for me!!  Although I'm using nano instead of emacs; putting 'export SVN_EDITOR=nano' in my .bashrc worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @user_v's answer:

To have the setting stick around, add SVN_EDITOR to the windows environmental variables.

To use a program under a path with spaces (like C:\Program Files) put the value in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

you need to logout and login if you add it to bashrc.

If you want to do it one time, and then add it, you can just do this on the command line (in bash)

SVN_EDITOR=emacs;export SVN_EDITOR

Answer (score 1):

Quick, but less powerful: Use the -m option to give the Commit Message directly as command line argument. E. g: `svn commit -m "Corrected cppcheck errors."`

Answer (score 0):

A nice trick with windows that solves this problem and lets you output the debug message to the console: write the command "set SVN_EDITOR=TYPE" in your CMD, I suggest the same works for Linux by setting SVN_EDITOR variable to "cat".