# subversion (svn) E205007 (commit failed). could not use external editor to fetch log message

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, cygwin

In Cygwin, in the directory containing `filename.xml`, this adds a file (working):

```
svn add filename.xml
```

this updates (working):

```
svn update
```

But this fails:

```
svn ci filename.xml
```

with the message:

> Error E205007 (commit failed).  Could not use external editor to fetch log message.

In Windows Explorer, if I right click and use TortoiseSVN "SVN Commit" this successfully commits the file.

How do I commit a file to SVN in Cygwin?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to include a message when you commit.  Use the command `svn ci filename.xml -m "your message here"`.  The message is a descriptor of what you are adding, and/or why you are adding it.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: [Why cant I use the $SVN_EDITOR environment variable in cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169241/why-cant-i-use-the-svn-editor-environment-variable-in-cygwin). You have to set a default editor for SVN, but just exporting EDITOR might do it.